# Team explorer in vs.net 2012 Build failed

Tags: visual-studio, tfsbuild

I have a vs.net 2012 asp.net c# solution which builds fine. However when I try to Build this trough an automatic build in TFS 2012 it ends with this error:

[image]

The message is sort of clear , dlls are not visible for the buildcontroller. The question is what is the path/location the put these dlls in?

Answer (score 2):

The path/location of the dll's doesn't matter as long as

- they're added to source control
- the folder they're in is mapped in the build definition workspace
- the relative path between the project and the dll is not different on the build server

The easiest method is to include them in a subfolder of your solution folder.

A better method is to use NuGet packages with restore on build enabled.